# Getting performance issue while clicking Test execution link. Tree is taking time to load

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, testlink

I am currently using Testlink1.9.3 for Test Management and execution of our project from last 5 years. 
First we started with Testlink1.6.3 version now I have migrated to 1.9.3.
Now I am getting performance issue while clicking Test execution link. Tree is taking time to load.

Detailed Information :

- The test link performance is quite slow.
- It is taking time to load the test project
- It is taking time to load the test plan
- While executing the test cases the performance is Fair
- While creating new plan/build the performance is Fair

Machine Details:

```
Database size is :- 193 MB

Database server detail
    Processor :- Intel Xeon CPU X3470  @ 2.93GHz
    RAM        :- 15GB

Application's H/W machine detail is as below
    Processor :-  Intel Core i3 CPU @ 2.93GHz                           
    RAM          :- 4GB
```

Configurations at the application level are set to have get best performance like making sure below parameters are set:

```
$g_use_ext_js_library = ENABLED;

$tlCfg->treemenu_type = 'EXTJS';
```

And double checked to see if there can be any other configuration improvements that can be made.

Logs:

> Use of undefined constant TL_LIGHTBOX_CSS - assumed 'TL_LIGHTBOX_CSS'
>   - in /var/www/html/thunder/gui/templates_c/%%56^560^56038526%%inc_head.tpl.php
>   - Line 40 [<<][512c073808f8a063878788][DEFAULT][/lib/execute/execNavigator.php][13/Feb/26
>   00:52:08][13/Feb/26 00:52:25][took 17.290396 secs]

I have also migrated 1.9.3 to 1.9.5 but performance issue is still there.

Any help on this would be highly appreciated. Still waiting for an expert answer.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this issue? I've stumbled on the same thing, and wondering what was the fix that worked for you!